# List is moving when I'm hover a tags

Tags: html, css

Hey I'm trying to create a web with a **nav bar**. However when I hover one a tag(link) all the others moves for some reason and I can't find a solution , guess some play with **css** which I'm still learning.... any help for what's wrong here?

```css
.container {
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  min-height: 70px;
}

header a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: color 0.3s;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

header a:hover {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-color: #2a2a2a;
  color: #D52B1E;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
}

header li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

header #logo {
  float: left;
}

header #logo h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="logo">
      <h1>Coupon<span style="color:#D52B1E">System</span></h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a routerLink="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

appreciate any help, thanks guys!

Comment: you are providing letter spacing on hover, either remove it completely or provide it in `header a` and then remove it from `header a:hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `letter-spacing: 1.5px;` in your `header a` class not on hover thats why its moving when you hover a `li`.

If you really want to show a little movement on hover you can try below method.

```css
.container {
    width: 85%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header {
    background-color: #262626;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 20px;
    min-height: 70px;
}

header a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: color 0.3s;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    position: relative;
}

header a:hover {
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-color: #2a2a2a;
    color: #D52B1E;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    right: 2px;

}

header li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

header #logo {
    float: left;
}

header #logo h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
}

header nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">
                <h1>Coupon<span style="color:#D52B1E">System</span></h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a routerLink="/home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a routerLink="/about">About</a></li>
                <li><a routerLink="/contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
```

I forgot this line in the a tag

Answer (score 0):

You're adding letting spacing to the `header a:hover`. This means whenever you hover over the link, letter spacing will be added.